# Power cable in 02 Chevy Suburban - where does it go?

Tags: electrical, sensor

I noticed on my 2002 Chevrolet Suburban that there’s a cable under the bonnet that’s unplugged and I’m trying to work out where it goes. I’ve included photos of it and where it runs. There’s no corresponding unplugged female connector that I can find anywhere.

I bought the vehicle fairly recently and as far as I’m aware it was unplugged when I bought it. The SUV has no issues except it occasionally gives an ABS warning light — I haven’t yet looked into that problem.

Does anyone know where that cable should be plugged in? Let me know if I need to provide any more info.

[image: Cable top view]

[image: Cable route]

Comment: I don't know the Suburban well enough to say definitively, however it is very possible this plug is simply not used. Manufacturers standardize components wherever they can, it's cheaper to make one wiring loom with connections for multiple models and options than customize each one.  There could be sensors that aren't needed on your engine, or electrical options your car doesn't have. In any case it's hard to tell because you've drawn over the connector.

Comment: I can't help off hand either, but you might consider going to a salvage yard and see if they have a comparable model you can compare with if no answer can be found elsewhere.

Comment: In the upper part of the top picture at the opposite end of the arrow (beginning of the line) is a body ground. I'm not sure where your plug goes, either, but think Jupiter's idea may have the best chance of helping you. This same wiring should be found on 2000-2006 Suburban, Tahoe, Silverado, & Sierra models with a V8, so plenty models which correspond. If I still had my '06 Silvy, I could figure it out pretty easily, lol.

Comment: Note that manufacturers are pretty careful when it comes to colored coded circuits. Carefully check the colors of the individual wires within the black convolute protective shield. Then find an accurate wiring diagram or electrical troubleshooting guide for that make and model. Wires have base color AND a stripe of color (e.g. “black/blue”) and that’s how they’re marked on each and every wiring diagram. Once you identify the colors involved it should be easy to find the circuit on a diagram.

Comment: @zipzit the cables are orange and black, I know that it is supposed to plug in to a sensor of some sort. I’m actually looking through the wiring diagrams in the back of my Haynes manual to see i I can identify it.

Comment: The pictures may not have been completely clear, but the wire runs to the electrical centre, which is why I don’t think it’s aftermarket.

Comment: Colors ALWAYS appear in pairs. Orange and ???, Black and ??? If it helps pull out a magnifying glass. The secondary color is a thin stripe. It’s pretty subtle. Note 2, while manufacturers often will give away circuits to reduce wire harness complexity they will NEVER leave a long pigtail unused. @GdD is well intended, but the cost, the potential for squeak/rattle, and customer questions (what is that for?) preclude it.

Comment: @zipzit Are you sure they always come in pairs? The black I’m fairly sure is ground, and in my Haynes manual wiring diagrams it lists a couple of only orange cables which go to battery+. I powered on the SUV and stuck a multimeter in the pins and it reads a steady 12V, so I’m wondering if those pins are just battery + and gnd.

Comment: Let me know if you want me to send you a photo of the wiring diagram or anything else.

Comment: Factory single colored wires are rare / non-existent, and that might indicate a really good aftermarket overlay. (perhaps for a dealer installed gps / sim card 'did you pay your monthly car payment?' repo the car box.)  I would pull an inch of unexposed wire out of the split black convolute, and check CLOSELY for the stripe color.  Its gotta be there.  That overlay sure looks factory original equipment.

Comment: Does the A/C work in this car?  Possible A/C clutch connector?

Comment: I will have a closer look for a stripe colour, do you have an example of what sort of thing I should be looking for?

Comment: The AC works just fine, and the compressor is on the opposite side of the engine.

Comment: That harness appears to be long enough to go to the passenger side of the engine.  [harness colors link](https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/7DgAAOSwiHFdaDq7/s-l400.jpg)  Because the stripe is painted on, you will want to look at a portion of the wire, not exposed to UV rays for 18 years... get a portion from out of the split convolute protective covering.. the paint there will be visible.

Comment: @zipzit I peeled back the loom and the wires are single-coloured the whole way, here’s a good pic of it: https://i.ibb.co/rmrLf4M/CFF235-B0-26-CD-4-CD0-BAF0-C955-ED96-DE4-D.jpg. I do think based on the colours listed in the wiring diagram in the Haynes manual that it’s a power cable, since all wires running to battery+ are single coloured and orange. I’ve no idea what it is supposed to be powering though.

Comment: My guess is the underhood light. Mine was mounted to the hood right above the master cylinder.

Comment: @mikes yes!! That’s definitely it, thank you. I just found a photo of one of them installed and I can see the wire originates from the same place: https://arthurrothsteinarchive.com/i/2020/02/best-under-hood-light-bar-jeep-yj-under-hood-light-under-hood-light-bar-harbor-freight-atd-underhood-light-336x280.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My 2002 Silverado had an under-hood light. It was mounted to the hood on the drivers side above the master cylinder. It may be the power for that.